# Javascript comfirmation message to stop form submission

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I have a web page where people can either save the form to be able to edit the info later again, or to submit the form. I want to add a confirmation message when the user clicks the submit button. If the user clicks 'Cancel' I want the form submission to be cancelled.

I tried the following, but it has no effect:

```
  const form = document.querySelector('#incidentform');

  form.addEventListener('onsubmit', function () {
    let text = "Are you sure you want to submit?";
    if (confirm(text) == true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: "Has no effect" as in doesn't show the confirmation message or doesn't cancel the form submission?

Comment: It does not cancel the form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const form = document.querySelector('#incidentform');

form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  let text = "Are you sure you want to submit?";
  if (!confirm(text)) {
event.preventDefault(); // Stops the form submission
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to cancel the default behavior of an event, You need to use [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

A shorter version of @AnishChittora code is :

```
const form = document.querySelector('#incidentform');

form.addEventListener('onsubmit', function (e) {
  if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to submit?"))
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Jquery - To implement a submit button with a confirmation box using jQuery, you can attach a click event handler to the button and display a confirmation dialog. If the user clicks "OK," the form will be submitted, and if the user clicks "Cancel," the form submission will be prevented.

Here's an example:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

   // Display the confirmation dialog
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the form?')) {
    // User clicked "OK" - submit the form
    $('#myForm').submit();
   } else {
   // User clicked "Cancel" - do nothing
  }
  });
 });
```